# Cancel auto-renewal subscriptions with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, renewal

I want to create a button where a user can cancel a auto-renewal subscription (or get redirected to App Store).

Is that possible without the user having to go through the whole purchase process first? If it is, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the Apple [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5) -

> Rather than needing to code your own subscription management UI, your
> app can open the following URL:
>
> https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
> Opening this URL launches iTunes or iTunes Store, and then displays
> the Manage Subscription page.

So, simply create a button that launches that URL.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions")!)
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you!

Comment: i received this message iTunes account creation not allowed. How to resolve this issue

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram Are you testing in the sandbox?  Subscription management is not available in the sandbox.  It is only available for production apps with production iTunes users

Comment: What to do in extensions where accessing UIApplication.sharedApplication (or shared now) is prevented?

Comment: You can't do it.

Answer (score 48):

**December 2019**

The correct URL is now https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions according to [Apple's Handling Subscriptions Billing Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/handling_subscriptions_billing).

So just use:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions")!)
```

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer. It should get more upvotes.

Comment: Just change openURL to open and will be up to date thanks!!
(openURL was deprecated on iOS 10 use open instead)
UIApplication.shared.open

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW19

So for Swift 3/4 just use this

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 and above

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

***April 2021***

According to the [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing), the URL has been updated to

```
https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions
```

So the following code can be used to redirect the user to manage subscriptions page.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate as it contains the same URL as my answer below.